# why client.smembers is not returning any members?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

im currently working on a chat application for the backend.here once we do `/chat` we are shown our friend list, from which we can start a conversation with anyone.in order to display the list of friends, i used `smembers` but its not returning any members even when i have friends added to my account.

```
app.get('/chat', utils.restrict, function(req,res){

  client.smembers('appname:users' + req.user.id + ':friends', function(err, members) {

        if (members && members.length > 0) {

          res.render('chat', {user: req.user, users : members});
      }
      else{
        res.send("No Friends Found!");
      }

    });
});
```

when i debug this, i see that the `client.smembers` line of code is hit but after that the value of `members` is given 0.i have required all of these too:

```
var app = module.parent.exports.app
, ACS = module.parent.exports.acs
, client = module.parent.exports.client
, passport = require('passport')
, config = require('../config')
, utils = module.parent.exports.utils;
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At last, after spending a lot of time i found out that the problem was with the database instance i was querying.I created a new instance of `redis` which did not have the data i wanted. i used `redis-cli` which  is the command line interface utility to talk with Redis.